# Shift subcaption of figure

Tags: subfloats, plot, subcaption

I'm using this code for ploting multiple plots:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=centering}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth} 
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./plots/gauss_pdf}
    \caption{}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./plots/gauss_cdf}
    \caption{}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./plots/gauss_joint}
    \caption{}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{(a) and (b) show the pdf and cdf of the standard normal distribution. The contours of a bivariate joint Gaussian is illustrated in (c)}
\label{rfidtag_testing}
\end{figure}
```

How can i achieve that (a), (b) and (c) fit to the center of the plots without the y-axis labels? The captions should have the same position as the x-axis label.

This produces:
[image]

Comment: You can move the \caption by placing it into a minipage with a smaller width.  The problem is determining the edge of the axis to be ignored.  I would put it inside an \fbox (\fboxsep=0pt) and measure the offset with a ruler.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that, to a fairly substantial degree, the apparent lack of centering of the "stubby" subfigure captions -- (a), (b), and (c) -- is actually an issue of your own making. Moreover, the issue can  be dealt with easily by slightly reorganizing just a few elements.

Specifically, I'd like to to make the following suggestions:

- Simplify the y-axes by omitting `\phi`, `\Phi`, and `x_2`, and make sure to crop the images tightly. The only labels on the y-axis should be numbers that don't take up much space.
- By providing terse sub-figure captions, it actually becomes very apparent if they're not centered. The remedy? Use longer, maybe even two-line captions; see below for a few suggestions. That way, any lack of "perfect" centering becomes much less likely to notice.
- Spread out the sub-figures horizontally by separating them by `\hfill` rather than just a inter-word space. This action will also help obscure any deviations from "perfect centering" of the subcaptions relative to their associated graphs.
- Simplify the overall `figure` caption.

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % remove 'demo' option in real doc.
\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption,xcolor}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=centering}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\textcolor{red}{\Large\ttfamily Before}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth} 
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./plots/gauss_pdf}
    \caption{}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./plots/gauss_cdf}
    \caption{}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./plots/gauss_joint}
    \caption{}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{(a) and (b) show the pdf and cdf of the standard normal distribution. The contours of a bivariate joint Gaussian is illustrated in (c)}
\label{first_try}
\end{figure}

\bigskip\noindent
\textcolor{red}{\Large\ttfamily After}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth} 
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./plots/gauss_pdf}
    \caption{Probability density function}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./plots/gauss_cdf}
    \caption{Cumulative distribution function}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./plots/gauss_joint}
    \caption{Bivariate normal: Equiprobability contours}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Standard normal or Gaussian distribution}
\label{second_try}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```